# How can I auto populate thumbnails from a url in excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have thousands of urls in an excel column and would love to have a lookup to then insert the image automatically into a cell to the right of the url name...can this be done either in excel or in google sheets?

Comment: Welcome to Super User. Please read **[ask]**, then update your question with details. As is, it is too vague to answer.

Answer (score 2):

Say the picture links are in column **A**.

First open your browser and then run this short macro:

```
Sub InstallPictures_2()
    Dim i As Long, v As String, shp As Shape
    For i = 1 To 1000
        v = Cells(i, "A").Value
        If v = "" Then Exit For
        With ActiveSheet.Pictures
            .Insert(v).Select
            Set shp = ActiveSheet.Shapes(Selection.Name)
            shp.Top = Cells(i, "B").Top
            shp.Left = Cells(i, "B").Left
            shp.Height = 100
            shp.Width = 100
        End With
    Next i

End Sub
```

For example:

[image]

Comment: Do you know if there is a way to create a macro that will "look up" in google or on a browser and then paste the picture that it finds?  Almost like going to a website like: 1800lighting.com and then typing in Schonbek 1707-20 and then pasting the picture it finds?

Comment: @JonMcMahan  ...................that I do not know.................